# Can not use public methods of subclasses java

Tags: java, swing

I am using NetBeans to create some desktop application with JTable-s and i have faced the trouble:

I am creating subclass of JTable, assume CustomJTable:

```
public class CustomJTable extends JTable {

    private Object[][] someData;

    public CustomJTable (Object[][] someData) {
        this.someData = someData;
    } 

    public doSomething () {
        // do something
    }
}

public class MyApp {

    ...
    public void someMethod (Object[][] someData) {
        JTable table = new CustomJTable(someData);
        table.doSomething();  // this method does not belong to JTable and    
                              // is unusable to me in NetBeans
    }
    ...
}
```

NetBeans says that doSomething method can not be found in class JTable. For nor I am really confused. Thanks in advice.

This is just a shortened sample code to show the trouble source.

Comment: Your variable type is JTable. And there is no such method in JTable. Change its type to CustomJTable. That said, subclassing swing components is generally a bad idea.

Comment: The method doSomething is missing a return type, it's a syntax error and will not compile, did you mean: public void doSomething() {}

Comment: Instead of `JTable table = new ...` use `CustomJTable table = new ...`

Answer (score 1):

You are instantiating instance of JTable and then try to call a method belong to CustomJTable.

Extending JTable in CustomJTable don't give you the methods owned by CustomJTable.

In order to call the method instantiate the right object:

```
CustomJTable table = new CustomJTable(someData);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of Runtime Polymorphism it will be resolved at runtime. You need to type cast it.

```
JTable table = new CustomJTable(someData);
        ((CustomJTable) table).doSomething();
```